# How to get data with condition in Grails controller?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

In my RideInfo domain class there is a field named giveRide. In the controller, I would like to get all data from table RideInfo whose giveRide equlas to TRUE, how can it do that? Thanks.

This piece of code doesn't work:

```
def listDriver = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    rideInfoInstance = RideInfo.get(giveRide=true)
    [rideInfoInstanceList: rideInfoInstance, rideInfoInstanceTotal: rideInfoInstance.count()]
}
```

Neither:

```
def listDriver = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    params.giveRide=true
    [rideInfoInstanceList: RideInfo.list(params), rideInfoInstanceTotal: RideInfo.count()]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RideInfo.getAllByGiveRide(true)
```

Comment: It replies:
Error 500: Executing action [listDriver] of controller [carpool.RideInfoController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: carpool.RideInfo.getAllByGiveRide() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]

Comment: Got it... def rideInfoInstance = RideInfo.findAllByGiveRide(true) Thanks!!